# mongo_mapper or mongoid with rails4

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongomapper

The ORM mongo_mapper and mongoid both support ruby on rails. However, after reading their documents I still cannot make a decision which one to use to develop a new application with rails4.

Any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958365/mongoid-or-mongomapper

Comment: It was answered in rails3 age. So do they still apply to rails4?

Answer (score 11):

I have used MongoMapper but decided to migrate to MongoId.
both of them are great MongoDB Libraries for Ruby, but after reading a lot about the difference, I ended up using mongoid because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10310284/2503775).

You can find some differences between those MongoDB Libraries here, and decide which of them is more suitable to your requirments:

- [Mongoid or MongoMapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958365/mongoid-or-mongomapper)
- [Mongoid vs MongoMapper: Two Great MongoDB Libraries for Ruby](http://www.rubyinside.com/mongoid-vs-mongomapper-two-great-mongodb-libraries-for-ruby-3432.html)
- [Mongoid or MongoMapper — the verdict](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9781849515023/5dot-ruby-datamappers-ruby-and-mongodb-go-hand-in-hand/id286769995)

Comment: did you have any issues switching? we're thinking about switching too and would love any advice.

Comment: Yes,sure.. Do you want me to send you a document, with all the issues switching?

Comment: we ran into a "TypeError: can't convert nil into String" error after converting ... did you see this?

Comment: never mind, we fixed this, but did you have an issue converting _id to id in mongoid? "id" is equivalent to "_id" in MM, but it doesn't work that way for mongoid it appears. did you get a chance to send any tips btw? thanks!

Comment: Yes... That is one of the problems that we also had. I'm writing the doc for you now..

Comment: cool, thanks! perhaps post as an answer, and we can credit you? i hope you found a solution for this because it's killing us right now. may have to stick with MM. :(

Comment: Why are you need to convert _id to id? record.id is the same as record._id in mongoid. I had a problem with it just because another service is using the db data as json, so I had to return `id` instead, or to change all my service code to `_id`.

Comment: yup, same thing as you ... other code relying on .id in the object JSON.

Comment: we found a good solution to the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892044/add-virtual-attribute-to-json-output. please include this in your answer then we can give you the points.

Comment: I posted it as an answer to your question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20947620/2503775. I will update it if I would remember more things...

Comment: I am thinking that in the most simple cases, you won't need either. This works for me: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver

Comment: I too used MongoMapper quite a bit, and decided to start using Mongoid instead.