# rails 4 with mongoid or mongomapper ? which is perfect for own product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongomapper

I am developing product which is fully relational. I researched on both options and I am happy with both documentations.  But I am still confused on - what to use ? Either go with Mongoid or Mongomapper?

I checked the link 
  [Mongoid or MongoMapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958365/mongoid-or-mongomapper)
which is very old. I want to know for today's date which option is suitable?

Comment: "fully relational" and MongoDB? There must be something wrong here... Use ActiveRecord and a SQL database.

Comment: Thanks for reply.... But actually its going to be very large database and at the same time required quick response which Mongodb can do. This is the reason I need to go with Mongo

Comment: In terms of performance MongoDB is much better than Mysql and this is what the basic need of product...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mongoid](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid) has been officially incorporated under the MongoDB umbrella. It is a more mature product and it's actively developed, compared with MongoMapper.

I'd definitely not use MongoMapper for a new project.

Comment: Thanks Simone .... I am starting with Mongoid as its officially incorporated under the MongoDB umbrella.